# Self-oscillating filter in NI Massive?

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer, synthesis

does anyone know if the filter in NI Massive can reach self-oscillation? I'm thinking about purchasing it but would just like to find this out beforehand. I can't really find any info on this elsewhere.
Cheers, Oli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-oscilation only works for analogue gear (because of the noise flow and constant active OSCs). Digital plug-ins can't self oscillate. But some programmers made algorithms that "imitate" self-oscillation to a certain degree. In NI Massive you can "imitate" self-osculation if you feed a bit to noise from the noise generator into the filter with a cranked resonance. Then after the self-osculation like sound starts you can remove the noise and the self-oscillation will feed itself.

Massive has a feedback function so you can feed back the output of the filter into the input and thus you can generate another self-osicillation like sound.

But if you want a real self-oscillating filter, you need to go analogue.

I hope I could answer you question.

Comment: Ah cool thanks. Yeah, I was just seeing If it could imitate. Ive had se pretty gold results from VSTi's. Once again, thanks.

Comment: Why would digital filter be unable to self-oscillate? Even an off-the-shelf biquad IIR can self-oscillate given suitable parameters – only that's normally prevented by the control interface, because with the oscillation will become louder without limit, which makes in unusable musically. But a digital filter with nonlinearities can self-oscillate in much the same, limited way as an analogue filter would. Self-oscillation has nothing to do with internal noise-floor.

Comment: If there is no signal to boost it can't resonate. So on a real digital synth you won't be able to self oscillate until you feed a small amount of noise into the filter. For en example -> Open up Massive use a 4 pole lp filter crank reso to max and you won't hear anything. On digital synths that model analogue synth you might get self oscillation ofc. But on a normal digital synth you won't.

Comment: Until you feed a small amount of _anything_ into the filter; this can also be a note you play through the oscillators, or merely an [anti-denormal offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number#Performance_issues). Again, the reason you won't hear anything when cranking up the reso on a normal digital synth is simply that it won't _allow_ you to crank it up beyond the critical point, because self-oscillation would be catastrophic. (In a dB scale the critical point is at +∞, but that does not correspond to infinite parameters of the underlying filter implementation.)

Comment: So do you mean that self oscillating digital filters would create an endless in volume increasing sound if not preserved by design? How come?

Comment: @TobiasSchmidt I believe this is because analog amplifiers do not have a linear gain at all amplitudes, so at some point the signal will reach a stable maximum voltage where the gain is exactly balanced by losses in the circuit. At some level, the volume of the analog system is limited by the energy you're providing it. In a digital filter using floating point samples, the "amplifier" is just a multiplication, which is linear up to an almost arbitrarily high value. The analog system's nonlinearity could certainly be simulated, but that would need to be specially designed in.

Comment: You can simulate any signal with a digital function, including resonance.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't entirely true. Soundtoys have a filter that can self oscillate. Check it out. It's one of the best filter vsts available.